# How is my DbContext being disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, dispose, dbcontext

I am having a great deal of difficulty in splitting my monolithic ASP.NET MVC application into an N-tier app. In the following example, during the first call to **_messageRepo.Create()** an exception is thrown saying that the **DbContext** cannot be used since it was already disposed.

I cannot see how that is happening, and attempting to break on the **Dispose()** method doesn't actually cause the application to break during debugging.

The basic structure is as follows:

- Controllers are injected with instances of each service they use //ie: public MyController(IMessageService messageService)
- Services contain any needed instances of repositories (ie: **_messageRepository**)
- Repositories utilize an instance of **MyContext**, a sub-class of **DbContext**
- These instances are reconstructed whenever needed as in the following example

  ```
  using(var context = new MyContext())
  {
      _messageRepo = new MessageRepository(context);
      _idRepo = new IdentityRepository(context);

      var status = _messageRepo.GetStatus(Int32.Parse(message.To));
      message.To = status.Header.From.Name;
      message.ToHash = Obfuscate.SaltAndHash(message.To);
      message.Subject = "RE:" + status.Header.Subject;

      var toUser = _idRepo.Get(message.To);
      var fromUser = _idRepo.Get(_userName);
      var rawMessage = new Message()
      {
          Content = message.Content,
          Attachments = GetAttachments(message.AttachmentIds)
      };
      var header = new MessageHeader()
      {
          To = toUser,
          From = fromUser,
          Subject = message.Subject
      };
      _messageRepo.Create(new MessageStatus()
      {
          CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
          IsRead = false,
          IsSpam = false,
          IsTrash = false,
          Message = rawMessage,
          Header = header,
          Owner = header.To
      });
      _messageRepo.Create(new MessageStatus()
      {
          CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
          IsRead = false,
          IsSpam = false,
          IsTrash = false,
          Message = rawMessage,
          Header = header,
          Owner = header.From
      });
      context.Commit();
      Email.SendNewMessageNotification(fromUser.Email, toUser.Email);
  }
  ```

The repository methods are LINQ one-liners that retrieve models from a database through Entity Framework using the code first approach.

Is there something wrong with this approach? I did have MyContext implement IUnitOfWork at first, but I removed that until I get this less complicated method functional.

Additionally, I am using an IoC framwork (AutoFac) to load instances of these interface implementations. If this is the problem, then what do I need to change about my logic to accomodate AutoFac?

```
//in Global.asax.cs
builder.RegisterType<PonosContext>().As<PonosContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

//Example repo constructor
public MessageRepository(PonosContext context)
{
    _db = context;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a IoC container, you should never call new of a service managed by the container. In this example you should not use:

```
using(var context = new MyContext())
_messageRepo = new MessageRepository(context);
_idRepo = new IdentityRepository(context);
```

Your dependencies should be injected (by constructor for example).

How do you register your repositories with AutoFac? Maybe you have your repositories configurard as singleton? This can cause the dispose exception when a repository is reused for a second http request.

Comment: Originally, I had my context wired in as one instance per HTTP request. That was throwing other EF exceptions, which lead me to this approach. Might I be able to get rid of all these using blocks by re-implenting MyContext as an IUnitOfWork and wiring that into AutoFac again with a different registration method?

Comment: Also, I was only able to access the DbSets within MyContext through (_unitOfWork as MyContext). I thought that was causing some different EF exceptions, is there a better way to have an interface in the constructor but access the underlying properties of the context as needed?

Answer (score 0):

DataContexts should not live too long :) They should be created and disposed close to their usage.

Consider not to pass the same instance between different repositories. If you want to wrap multiple operations in a single transaction, look at [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Comment: Although I agree with that mindset, I need to be able to use the results from one repo call (GetStatus()) as the input for a model that is passed into other repo calls. If I dispose the context in between those steps, then accessing the lazy loaded members of MessageStatus will throw an exception about the context being disposed.

Comment: After seeing your note about TransactionScope, I tried wrapping the above example in another using block, but scope.Complete after using the context doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: IMHO should should use the same Context during a single service/http call. A DbContext represents a UnitOfWork which is a business transaction, so it make sense that all the modifications for a single operation (service/http call) are made through the same DbContext. Your DbContext should never live longer as a Http call. But is you use different DbContext's during the same operation, you loose a lot of benefits of youre ORM.

Comment: no, as Tim wrote DbContext is your unit of work so should be passed between repositories. If you do this, all your updates will be committed within an implicit transaction created by EF and you do not need to use TransactionScope (which can result in distributed transactions if you are not careful).